# Is there a C/C++ API for python pandas?

Tags: python, c, api, pandas

I'm extracting mass data from a legacy backend system using C/C++ and move it to Python using `distutils`. After obtaining the data in Python, I put it into a pandas DataFrame object for data analysis. Now I want to go faster and would like to avoid the second step.

Is there a C/C++ API for pandas to create a DataFrame in C/C++, add my C/C++ data and pass it to Python? I'm thinking of something that is similar to numpy C API.

I already thougth of creating numpy array objects in C as a workaround but i'm heavily using timeseries data and would love to have the TimeSeries and date_range objects as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the pandas classes (TimeSeries, DataFrame, DatetimeIndex etc.) have pure-Python definitions so there isn't a C API.  You might be best off passing numpy ndarrays from C to your Python code and letting your Python code construct pandas objects from them.

If necessary you could use `PyObject_CallFunction` etc. to call the pandas constructors, but you'd have to take care of accessing the names from module imports and checking for errors.

Comment: Thanks ecatmur! I'll give the ndarrys a try...

Answer (score 20):

There is now a C++ library that is equivalent to Pandas package in terms of interface and functionality.
See this article in Linkedin "https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/pythons-pandas-c-update-hossein-moein/"
The open source code is in "https://github.com/hosseinmoein/DataFrame"

Comment: Please post self-contained explanations on StackOverflow - if the links disappear, this answer will be useless.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher If the links disappear, in this case, the answer will be useless regardless of its self-containment.

Comment: Vaex is pretty awesome: https://towardsdatascience.com/beyond-pandas-spark-dask-vaex-and-other-big-data-technologies-battling-head-to-head-a453a1f8cc13

Answer (score 17):

I am dealing with a similar problem, loading data from a format unsupported by Pandas with a C API. I found two ways to address this, hopefully someone might find them useful.

- The Pandas data frames are pure Python classes, so they are not easy to construct from C/C++, but the underlying data storage of the individual columns [(see class Series source)](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L88) is numpy 1D array. Numpy has a nice [C API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/c-api.html) and you can construct the numpy arrays from C and then pass it to your Python code.
- A second solution is to write your own input module for Pandas. This is not as much work as it sounds and might be very efficient. The Pandas low-level IO modules are written in [Cython](http://cython.org/) (a special language somewhere between Python and C, compiled to C), see e.g. [parser.pyx](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/parser.pyx) for an example. While that particular parser is quite involved, yours would basically just call your legacy C code.